# How to disable codeigniter debug mode

Tags: codeigniter

I am using codeigniter logger using following configuration :

$config['log_threshold'] = 4;

These are 5 threshold used in application/config/config.php

```
 0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
   2 = Debug Messages
   3 = Informational Messages
   4 = All Messages
```

I only want to use threshold 1 and 3. 
If i use 4 in threshold i am able to print log message with many debug message. These debug messages will fill my server space. So i want to disable this debug mode.

I am using codeigniter version 2.2.0

Here is my log file :

```
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> Config Class Initialized
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> Hooks Class Initialized
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> URI Class Initialized
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> Router Class Initialized
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> Output Class Initialized
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> Security Class Initialized
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> Input Class Initialized
  DEBUG - 2015-09-14 17:17:22 --> Global POST and COOKIE data sanitized
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CI3 you can pass array of cases/keys you want to be written. 
In CI2 you would need to switch places of keys in array `$_levels` on ln 34 of `BASEPATH . 'Log.php'` file or if you don't want to mess up with system files (which should be kind of good behavior) you can make extension of library:

```
class MY_Log extends CI_Log
{
    protected $_levels  = array('ERROR' => '1', 'INFO' => '2',  'DEBUG' => '3', 'ALL' => '4');
/**
 * Constructor
 */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

I believe this way it should work too.

Comment: I switch the places of keys in my existing system/libraries/Log.php and i use 
$config['log_threshold'] = array(3, 1);

It did not solve my problem.

Comment: If you have set array like in example I showed, try with `$config['log_threshold'] = 2;`

Comment: Thanks. It works for me.
I am seeing following error message : ERROR - 2015-09-23 17:52:11 --> Severity: 8192  --> mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

If i change my db driver name to mysqli , All mysql fuctions stop working
please suggest how can i remove this error message from loggers

Comment: How do you mean: you want only info shown in log, not errors?

Comment: Actually i need both error and info message but i want to remove this message from loggers : ERROR - 2015-09-23 17:52:11 --> Severity: 8192 --> mysql_pconnect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90444/discussion-between-nilesh-kumar-and-tpojka).

Comment: In `APPPATH . 'config/database.php'` file try with changing `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';` to `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Comment: Yes i did same change in my code but mysql function stop working like : mysql_real_escape_string().
Because we have changed dbdriver to mysqli from mysql.

Comment: mysql functions are not considered as secured. So smart move would be refactoring code mysql => mysqli.